# Display chess pieces in GridView

Tags: java, android, xml, chess

I'm using a 8*8 GridView and a SquareAdapter that extends BaseAdapter to make a chess board.

My question is:  how should I display the pieces in their places?

this is SquareAdapter class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class SquareAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    FrameLayout flcp;
    ImageView imgvcp = null;

    private int whiteTurn;


    // CHESSBOARD

    private Integer[] chessboardIds = {
            R.drawable.lightsquare, R.drawable.darksquare, R.drawable.lightsquare, R.drawable.darksquare,
            R.drawable.lightsquare, R.drawable.darksquare, R.drawable.lightsquare, R.drawable.darksquare,
            R.drawable.darksquare, R.drawable.lightsquare, R.drawable.darksquare, R.drawable.lightsquare,
            R.drawable.darksquare, R.drawable.lightsquare, R.drawable.darksquare, R.drawable.lightsquare,
            R.drawable.lightsquare, R.drawable.darksquare, R.drawable.lightsquare, R.drawable.darksquare,
            R.drawable.lightsquare, R.drawable.darksquare, R.drawable.lightsquare, R.drawable.darksquare,
            R.drawable.darksquare, R.drawable.lightsquare, R.drawable.darksquare, R.drawable.lightsquare,
            R.drawable.darksquare, R.drawable.lightsquare, R.drawable.darksquare, R.drawable.lightsquare,
            R.drawable.lightsquare, R.drawable.darksquare, R.drawable.lightsquare, R.drawable.darksquare,
            R.drawable.lightsquare, R.drawable.darksquare, R.drawable.lightsquare, R.drawable.darksquare,
            R.drawable.darksquare, R.drawable.lightsquare, R.drawable.darksquare, R.drawable.lightsquare,
            R.drawable.darksquare, R.drawable.lightsquare, R.drawable.darksquare, R.drawable.lightsquare,
            R.drawable.lightsquare, R.drawable.darksquare, R.drawable.lightsquare, R.drawable.darksquare,
            R.drawable.lightsquare, R.drawable.darksquare, R.drawable.lightsquare, R.drawable.darksquare,
            R.drawable.darksquare, R.drawable.lightsquare, R.drawable.darksquare, R.drawable.lightsquare,
            R.drawable.darksquare, R.drawable.lightsquare, R.drawable.darksquare, R.drawable.lightsquare,
    };

    static class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView square;
        public ImageView piece;
    }


    public SquareAdapter(Context c/*, Piece[] listPiece, int turn*/) {
        mContext = c;
        Context context = c.getApplicationContext();
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return chessboardIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;
        if (rowView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes

            rowView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.square, null);


            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.square = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.square_background);
            viewHolder.square.setImageResource(chessboardIds[position]);
            viewHolder.piece = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.piece);

            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
```

main layout file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".ChessActivity" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:numColumns="8"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="0dp">
    </GridView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

square.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/square"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="#000080"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/square_background"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:padding="0dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/piece"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="0dp"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

this is the result:

[image: this is how much I've gone so far]

Comment: check if grid position mod (%2) is equal 0,then set background white(#ffffff) else set background black (#000000)

Comment: @Mohit He has to check if `(x+y)%2==0`

Comment: You can do it by just checking position...just define gridview column statically and put check on every cell position..